# Rails 4 ActionMailer around_action | access action information (action_name & parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building an `around_action` for my `customer_mailer` class so that I don't have to wrap `begin and rescue` around every time I call `deliver_now`

```
class CustomerMailer < ApplicationMailer
  around_action :rescue_error

  def send_email(customer)
    ...
  end

  def invite_friend(customer, invitee_email)
    ...
  end

  private
    def rescue_error
      yield
    rescue => e
      msg = "Caught exception! #{e} | #{action_name}"
      puts msg
      raise
     end
end
```

So in the rescue, I want to log the message with information such as which action was called, I managed to find the method `action_name` to show which action was called, but I couldn't find a way to retrieve the parameters that were passed into the action, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I answer your question: would using Bugsnag or something similar work in your case? Alternatively would `rescue_from Exception, with: :exception_handler` work for you? (it won't allow you to reraise the exception though)

---

I dug into Rails source code and it seems that parameters are *not* stored anywhere. They are just passed as a splat to an instance method defined in your mailer class. However, there *is* a way to store them (without monkey-patching).

Mailers inherit from `AbstractController::Base`. Looking at the snippet below:

```
  # Call the action. Override this in a subclass to modify the
  # behavior around processing an action. This, and not #process,
  # is the intended way to override action dispatching.
  #
  # Notice that the first argument is the method to be dispatched
  # which is *not* necessarily the same as the action name.
  def process_action(method_name, *args)
    send_action(method_name, *args)
  end

  # Actually call the method associated with the action. Override
  # this method if you wish to change how action methods are called,
  # not to add additional behavior around it. For example, you would
  # override #send_action if you want to inject arguments into the
  # method.
  alias send_action send
```

we can see that we can override `#send_action` and make it store the arguments. Add the following to your `ApplicationMailer`:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def send_action(method_name, *args)
    @action_args = args
    super
  end
end
```

The arguments will be available as `@action_args` in all your mailers.

Comment: I like this though I rather *would* call this monkey-patching as you override an internal rails method.

Comment: I like this approach, I don't have time to check it now, but I will definitely test it later. I'm not using `rescue_from` because I think it's not available for action_mailer in rails 4, but it will be in rails 5?

Comment: @lusketeer, `rescue_from` _is_ available in Rails 4. You can take a look at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from). @BoraMa, this method is _not_ internal. It's `private` but the design allows a subclass to override it.

Comment: @GregNavis thanks, it works great. For `rescue_from`, the documentation stated that it's in `ActionController` but not `ActionMailer`, as far as I know that it's available for `ActionController` and `ActiveJob` for rails 4, but coming in rails 5 for `ActionMailer`, [https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25018](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25018)

Comment: I'm happy it works. Regarding `rescue_from`, you're correct, @lusketeer. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the parameters with which the action has been called to an instance variable, say `@params`. Then these parameters will be accessible in `rescue_error` via `@params`. As per your example:

```
class CustomerMailer < ApplicationMailer
  around_action :rescue_error

  def send_email(customer)
    @params = { customer: customer }
    ...
  end

  def invite_friend(customer, invitee_email)
    @params = { customer: customer, invitee_email: invitee_email }
    ...
  end

  private

  def rescue_error
    begin
      yield
    rescue => e
      msg = "Caught exception! #{e} | #{action_name} | #{@params.inspect}"
      puts msg
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

You can make the assignment to `@params` a bit cleaner by using hash parameters in your actions, e.g.

```
def invite_friend(options = {})
  @params = params
  ...
end
```

Of course, this requires accessing the parameters via `options`, such as `options[:customer]` to access `customer`, and `options[:invitee_email]` to access `invitee_email`.

Comment: this is what I'm kinda doing currently that I'm creating an instance variable for each passed in variable, but I wanted to make it more dynamic without going through the trouble to initialize them every time I create an action. but this one is simple and clean, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The action name  have to be yielded , it depends on the way you use your rescue_error .

Define a variable in the block that will be yielded

or raise specifics errors (maybe your custom exception class ) 
this way you'll retrieve invormation via "e"

post an exemple use case of rescue_error.